# I can't access my variable in a separate method

Tags: java

I have to make a program that draws a Sierpinski Triangle.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class SierpinskiPanel extends JPanel{

    private SierpinskiFrame frame;

    public SierpinskiPanel(SierpinskiFrame f){
        frame = f;
    }
```

That said, I am unable to access variable g in my recursive method. How would I go about making the variable accessible, or putting the method inside of method paintComponent?

```
    public void drawSierp(int width, int height, int x, int y){
        int leftCornY = height;
        int rightCornY = height;
        int rightCornX = width;
        if(width == 1 && height == 1){
            g.drawRect(x, y, 1, 1);
        }
        else{
            drawSierp(width/4, height/4, x, leftCornY);
            drawSierp(width/4, height/4, rightCornX, rightCornY);
            drawSierp(width/4, height/4, width/2, height/2);
        }
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        int w = frame.getWidth();
        int h = frame.getHeight();
        int xCoord = frame.getX();
        int yCoord = frame.getY();
        drawSierp(w, h, xCoord, yCoord);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your method to be

```
public void drawSierp(Graphics g, int width, int height, int x, int y)
```

and call it initially from `paintComponent` as

```
drawSierp(g, w, h, xCoord, yCoord);
```

Of course, you will need to pass it from your `else` block calls as well.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't passed the object `g` to `drawSierp()`. So the method should get the incoming parameters.

```
public void drawSierp(int width, int height, int x, int y, Graphics g){
        int leftCornY = height;
        int rightCornY = height;
        int rightCornX = width;
        if(width == 1 && height == 1){
            g.drawRect(x, y, 1, 1);
        }
        else{
            drawSierp(width/4, height/4, x, leftCornY, g); // Pass the object g'
            drawSierp(width/4, height/4, rightCornX, rightCornY, g); // Pass the object 'g'
            drawSierp(width/4, height/4, width/2, height/2 , g); // Pass the object 'g'
        }
    }
```

When you call the function, you should give all the parameters.